# jQuery Progressbar Moving

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, progress-bar

I have a jQueryUI progressbar, and after a series of moving it around with my own javascript code, it starts rapidly moving forwards and backwards. Here is the relevant javascript code: (Requires Console Input)

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#progressbar").progressbar({ value: 0 });
    });

    var pr = 0;
    var goTo = 0;
    var speedType = "fast";

    function prgMax(speed){
        speedType = speed;
        if(speedType == "slow") {
            if(pr < 101) {
                pr=pr+0.2;
                $("#progressbar").progressbar({ value: pr });
                var t = setTimeout('prgMax("slow")', 0.1);
            }
            else{ return "Moved"; clearTimeout(); }
        }
        else {
            if(pr < 101) {
                pr=pr+1;
                $("#progressbar").progressbar({ value: pr });
                var t = setTimeout(prgMax, 0.1);
            }
            else{ return "Moved"; clearTimeout(); }
        }
    }

    function prgMin(speed){
        speedType = speed;
        if(speedType == "slow") {
            if(pr > -1) {
                pr=pr-0.2;
                $("#progressbar").progressbar({ value: pr });
                var t = setTimeout('prgMin("slow")', 0.1);
            }
            else{ return "Moved"; clearTimeout(); }
        }
        else {
            if(pr > -1) {
                pr=pr-1;
                $("#progressbar").progressbar({ value: pr });
                var t = setTimeout(prgMin, 0.1);
            }
            else{ return "Moved"; clearTimeout(); }
        }
    }

    function prgSet(setting,speed){
        speedType = speed;
        goTo = setting
        if(speedType == "slow") {
            if(goTo > pr) {
                pr=pr+0.2;
                $("#progressbar").progressbar({ value: pr });
                var t = setTimeout('prgSet(goTo,speedType)',0.1);
            }
            else if(goTo < pr) {
                pr=pr-0.2;
                $("#progressbar").progressbar({ value: pr });
                var t = setTimeout('prgSet(goTo,speedType)',0.1);
            }
            else if(goTo == pr) { return "Moved"; clearTimeout(); }
        }
        else {
            if(goTo > pr) {
                pr=pr+1;
                $("#progressbar").progressbar({ value: pr });
                var t = setTimeout('prgSet(goTo,speedType)',0.1);
            }
            else if(goTo < pr) {
                pr=pr-1;
                $("#progressbar").progressbar({ value: pr });
                var t = setTimeout('prgSet(goTo,speedType)',0.1);
            }
            else if(goTo == pr) { return "Moved"; clearTimeout(); }
        }
    }
```

And my HTML

```
<div style="height:32px; display:inline-block; left:39px; right:5px; position:absolute;" id="progressbar"></div>
```

I fixed part of the problem by adding clearTimeout() to the else if statements, but the progressbar starts moving back and forth when I put the following series into the console:

```
prgMax() //Wait until it's done then
prgMin("slow") //Wait until it's done then
prgSet(5,"slow")
```

Does anyone have any ideas? Thanks in advance, and comment if something doesn't make sense!

Answer (score 1):

You should not use strings in [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout) but a function. Also, `0.1` milliseconds is probably too short, the minimal value browsers can handle is about 4 ms.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use a simple and nice progressbar. This one doesn't have jQuery and it's very easy to use: http://ruwix.com/simple-javascript-html-css-slider-progress-bar/